# Firebase Firestore is not returning data from documents flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch data from documents in firestore through a method to print it for a chat app (part of the course i'm studying) but it doesn't work

```
void messegesStream() async {
await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
  for (var message in snapshot.docs) {
    print(message.data);
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("messages").getDocuments();
  for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.documents.length; i++) {
    print(querySnapshot.documents[i]);
  }
```

and ensure that you have any documents in the root collection "messages".

Comment: it will not help cause i want to use it in a StreamBuilder but thnx for the answer